# How to prevent false red highlighted code lines in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Today I open the code on Visual Studio and all the code emphasized in red appears as if there is an error throughout the code. But the code anyway works well and has no errors.
How can I remove this visual study behavior?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it say there's an error? 
If you format it with Shift+Alt+F does it look incorrectly formatted, or does the formatting look worse?
Is there a stray character, perhaps a bracket { or parenthesis ( without it's closing partner?

Comment: @DonaldDuck if I format nothing happens, for the rest the code works as it should, so there is no shortage of parentheses or anything else

Comment: Is there an error message showing when your cursor hovers over some red underlined text?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I edit the post with the errors coming out. They are not all, as I said it gives me errors on the whole file.

Comment: Your errors seems to be related to prettier/eslint. Try to reset any recent settings changes you made in those extensions.

Comment: @ISAE How can I do it?